# Circular dependency when generating dbcontext migrations into another assembly

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

As the name suggests I have multiple projects, and one of the project contains the dbcontext and all the models. So, I want to generate migrations from that project and put all generated migrations into another assembly (*because I have multiple db providers for the same dbcontext, and one way is to move all migrations in different assemblies, so, i dont have problems later.*).

Project containing the dbcontext and other stuff is not my main project, is just a class library.

The structure of the solution looks like below:

- MyProject.DbContext
- MyProject.DbContext.Migrations
- MyProject

**So, I reference the project `MyProject.DbContext.Migrations` from `MyProject.DbContext` to make the `dotnet ef ...` work,** and I run this command:

`dotnet ef migrations add InitMySql --project ..\MyProject.DbContext.Migrations`

This will work fine as long as I do sth like this:

```
 optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseMySql(configuration.ConnectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(configuration.ConnectionString), builder =>
 {
      builder.CommandTimeout(configuration.CommandTimeout);
      builder.UseNewtonsoftJson();
      builder.MigrationsAssembly("MyProject.DbContext.Migrations");
  });
```

But, now I have a big problem, the project `MyProject.DbContext.Migrations` needs also reference to `MyProject.DbContext` because of the new class created 'MyDbContextModelSnapshot' which has an attribute at the top: `[DbContext(typeof(MyDbContext))]` etc. Now I run into a circular dependency issue!

How is this supposed to be solved ?

I am currently using Asp.Net core 5, but I think this will happen for any version, seems more like a design limitation...

Comment: I don't think the context assembly needs to reference the migrations assembly at all.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman when i dont reference it I get: `Could not load assembly 'MyProject.DbContext.Migrations'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'MyProject.DbContext'.` Also tried commenting out this `     builder.MigrationsAssembly("MyProject.DbContext.Migrations");` but still the same

Comment: Perhaps this "Tip" is the reason? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#steps

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yeah seems like a limitation and is very error prone to my opinion. Seems I will have to move them manually all the time, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Here describe how to use multi providers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Migrations project `BaseOutputPath` to be the `bin` folder of your main running project.
Example: `..\MyProject.API`.
This way you don't have the circular dependency problem, and the project containing the `DbContext` won't complain about the missing reference.

This can be configured in the project properties or by editing the .csproj directly.